# How to prefix / suffix column names in a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, session

I'm storing the user type (seller or buyer) in one of my session variables as `$_SESSION['user_type']`.

Some of my select / insert / update queries require the columns by the name of `seller_id` or `buyer_id`.

I want to know if there's a way by which I can add the `_id` suffix to `$_SESSION['user_type']` in my queries.

For example: If I want to select all the columns from my `order` table where `buyer_id` is equal to `7`, my query should look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `order`
WHERE ( $_SESSION['user_type'] + "_id" ) = '7'
```

**Note:** I know I can use a variable and generate the corresponding column name, but was wondering whether this is possible without any extra variable.

Comment: your simply building a string, like any other

Comment: can't we generate the string in the query itself?

Comment: the query is a string

Comment: doesn't that mean we can add the suffix in the query (since it's a string)?

Comment: sure can, whats the probelm

Comment: you want to **concatenate**. you do this with a period `.` not a plus `+`

Comment: Got it! Was trying something else..

Comment: oh you had the *something else* bug, hate that one :-)

Comment: Beside the main problem, if you're including user input, to avoid SQL injection hacks, you should consider using prepared statements.

Comment: @Dagon All my queries had `$_SESSION['user_type']` withing the string query like `SELECT * FROM order WHERE $_SESSION['user_id'] ) = '7'` without use of `.`. Didn't realise that I could have used them.

Comment: ok -- this has nothing to do with mysql or sessions, its basic php strings.

Comment: @JonathanM Sure will. Just started with SQL. :)

Comment: @Dagon I understand that, but I always wonder how come queries directly read the variable values within the `" "` itself. I mean why don't they need separators? Shouldn't it be like `"SELECT * FROM order WHERE" .  $_SESSION['user_id'] . "= '7'"` always? However it works without separators.

Comment: no idea what you just asked

Comment: I mean in general, while concatinating string with variables we separate them by `"`, however in queries we don't need to do that. That is, the variable name is a part of the string query itself.

Comment: no, its no difference, its all php strings http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php nothing to do with being used as a query

Comment: Technically (by string format), the query `"SELECT * FROM $table_name"` (say `$table_name = "seller"`) should be `"SELECT *  FROM " . $table_name`. But the former works in case of php (which is not allowed in other languages).

Comment: no both are valid php strings, any variable inside double quotes is evaluated by the server.

Comment: exactly, but that doesn't happen in general programming! ;)

Comment: yes it does. any php string http://ideone.com/2OSeC4

Comment: @theScorpion, I think the syntax you were looking for was: `"SELECT * FROM order WHERE {$_SESSION['user_id']} ) = '7'"`. Notice that `$_SESSION['user_id']` is wrapped in `{}`'s.

Comment: @Dagon I've seen that in php only like I said before. I wonder how can we just print the variable names (without allowing the server to process it).

Comment: ?!?!?!?!!? nope i give up read the manual for the love of Buddha.

Comment: @Dagon how would you echo the string "$dog" (not variable) without storing it another variable? I will for the love of Buddha. :)

Comment: `echo ' $dog '; `//output = *$dog* http://ideone.com/2OSeC4

Comment: I meant echoing "$dog" when $dog = "dog". Saw the documentation -- it would be `echo "\$dog";` instead. See, I do love Buddha. :) (PS: Sorry for the trouble caused.) http://ideone.com/s4YHjQ

Comment: `echo "$".$dog;`
 or 
`echo '$'.$dog;`

Comment: Should have [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php#answer-3446286).

Comment: should of read the link to the manual i gave you an hour ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate query as string and use it then.

```
$query = "SELECT *
    FROM `order`
    WHERE " . $_SESSION['user_type'] . "_id = '7'";
```

But make sure that you'll not include anything from user input in such way.

Answer (score 0):

*If i see old post with possible SQL-Injections i have post ...*

If you have to use the value of a variable in a query then

**use a whitelist** - Please!

Example:

```
// even if its a session stored on your server and the values set by your self ...
// do NOT trust it and handle it as any other value from any other varible.
// example input:
// $_SESSION['user_type'] = 'seller';

// define the map of valid session user types and column relations (hardcoded)
$columnMap = [
    // user_type => column name
    'buyer'  => 'buyer_id',
    'seller' => 'seller_id',
];

// check if you got a valid session type (if you find it on the white list)
if (!isset($columnMap[$_SESSION['user_type']])) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid session[user_type].");
}
// use the value from the white list
$columnName = $columnMap[$_SESSION['user_type']];

// create proper query
$query = "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE `{$columnName}` = :id;";

// Note:
// "SELECT * FROM `order` WHERE
//     `{$columnName}`  -- use ` to enclose the column name
//      = :id           -- use placeholder (prepared statements f.e. PHP PDO)
//     ;                -- finish statement with semicolon
// "
```

PHP PDO: https://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepared-statements.php

*Why?*

Because code may change over years and you get the (i.e.) user_type from a POST or GET request.

*Still - why?*

Go search for "SQL-Injections".